# Stopovers between Hawaii, Conus and back

Tags: stopovers, hawaii, open-jaw

I would like to fly from Hawaii and make short stopovers of 2-3 days each in San Diego or Phoenix, St. Louis and Burlington, VT or Montreal.

What would be the cheapest way to do this, utilizing stopovers and open jaws w/award miles/segments and/or paid for?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please have a read of our [help]  - asking people to be travel agents for you is considered offtopic.  I can however, recommend that either you reword, if possible, after reading the [help], or consider a crowdsourced site like [Flightfox](http://www.flightfox.com).

Comment: Also, please do not type in all capital letters. It has long been considered as "shouting" on the internet.